# How to say "to review an academic paper" in Japanese

Tags: words, word-requests

How to say "to review an academic paper" in Japanese?

By "reviewing" I refer to "the process of having a draft version of a researcher's methods and findings reviewed (usually anonymously) by experts (or "peers") in the same field. Peer review helps the academic publisher (that is, the editor-in-chief, the editorial board or the program committee) decide whether the work should be accepted, considered acceptable with revisions, or rejected for official publication in an academic journal, a monograph or in the proceedings of an academic conference."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholarly_peer_review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [査読](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9F%BB%E8%AA%AD) in kango. It also works as a transitive suru-verb, so you can say 論文(原稿)を査読する. (ピア)レビュー is also common and safely understood (at least by researchers). *Reviewer* is 査読者 or レビュアー.